# Responsive Navigation (If Button comes to the left screen navigation resizes automaticly)

Tags: html, css, button, navigation, responsive

at the moment I'm trying to create a responsive Navigation but I've some struggle with the buttons in the navigation.
I'm trying to create a Home Button (on the left side) a Text (in the middle) and a further button (on the right) in a row (with some margins). Every time when I'm resizing the screen the navigation won't be in a row anymore if the button on the left comes to the screen end.

I've created a small gif: [http://i.imgur.com/3k31cnl.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/3k31cnl.gifv)

```css
.responsive ul { 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none; }

.responsive ul li { display: inline-block; }

/* Header Home Button Logged OUT */

    .btn-home {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #383838;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 13px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius:8px;
    margin-top: 0.25em;
    margin-right:50em;

    font: bold 1.3em/165% "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .btn-home:hover {
        background-color: #008CBA;
        color: white;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

/*Welcome Message*/
    .text-welcome{
        position: relative;

        margin-top: 1%;
        font: bold 1.3em/165% "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    
/*LogoutButton*/

.btn-logout {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #d9534f;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 3px 13px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: -2.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius:8px;

}

.btn-logout:hover {
    background-color: #008CBA;
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
    .logout-icon:after {
        content: '\f08b';
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        padding-left: 5px;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="responsive">   
    <ul>
    <!-- Home Button --> 
        <li>
            <a href="https://craftonia.net" class="btn-home" >Home</a>
        </li>
    <!-- Welcome -->
        <li>
            <div class="text-welcome">
                <p> Herzlich Willkommen&nbsp;<span style="color:#ff0000;">{{ cart.player.username }}</span></p>
            </div>
        </li>
    <!-- LogoutButton -->
        <li>
            <div class="headerpos">
                <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="btn-logout logout-icon"></a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```